# Databind iron-ajax JSON response entry to nested Polymer custom elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer, polymer-1.0

I've got a Polymer app running an iron-ajax call to a service that returns a json string:

```
{
    "name": "John"
}
```

The Polymer code on the main page is:

```
<link rel="import" href="/elements/my-form.html">

<dom-module id="my-app">

    <template>

        ...

        <iron-ajax auto url="/grabData" handle-as="json" last-response="{{data}}"></iron-ajax>

        <iron-label>
            From iron-ajax = {{data.name}}
        </iron-label>

        <my-form></my-form>

       ...
```

"my-form" is:

```
<link rel="import" href="/my-name.html">

<dom-module id="my-form">

    <template>
        <my-name></my-name>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-form'
        });
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

And "my-name" is:

```
<dom-module id="my-name">

    <template>
        <iron-label>
            From my-name = {{data.name}}
        </iron-label>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-name'
        });
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

When run, "From iron-ajax = John", and "From my-name =".

While I could use a single ajax call within my-name, I'd don't want to do this for every custom element.  I'd rather acquire my data in one call and have custom elements access the returned data.

How do I acquire 'name' within my-name without passing the value through the my-form element?

--- Update ---

For a little more clarity on desired outcomes, here's a little more info.

Ultimately I'd like to acquire a very large JSON string with multiple entries:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "address": [{
        "street" : "14 Baker Street",
        "city" : "somewhereville"
    }],
    "phone": "123-1234"
    ...
}
```

And have custom elements handle each entry:

```
<dom-module id="my-form">

    <template>
        <my-name></my-name>
        <my-address></my-address>
        <my-phone></my-phone>
        ...
    </template>
```

Comment: I've only used ajax results inside their own template. Not sure if it's possible to do otherwise, though I'm no polymer expert.

Comment: I've done the same.  I'd prefer to make one call since I need to return several data items.

Comment: Maybe you could use [iron-meta](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-meta)

Comment: You can either store it in `localStorage` or you can fire an [iron-signal](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-signals) which will contain the data and can listen to that signal in your `my-name` element. Thoughi'll recommend passing the data through `my-form` element through `data-binding`.

Comment: @a1626 Yep, my fallback was: "<my-form data={{data}}></my-form>" & then "<my-name name={{data.name}}></my-name>".  I was hoping to be less verbose, though it is more in line with the MVC pattern.  Is this what you were referring too?

Comment: Correct, but if you need to pass name only then it can be `<my-form name={{data.name}}></my-form>` & then `<my-name name={{name}}></my-name>`, otherwise you can look into iron-signals.

Comment: You can also try [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-attributeFollows). I've never really used it so can't say anything about it, but looks like it can remove the `data` or `name` object from `my-form`

Comment: @a1626 Sounds like that is my best option.  Would you mind posting it as an answer?  Also, I'm not sure at this time so if you can clarify, do I need to specify a property 'name' in my-name for this work?  Maybe some sample code would be enlightening :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the example snippet on how to pass data between elements. Instead of `ajax call` i've passed data from element's attribute. Some key points to be noted

- In case you want to pass whole data to child elements you can replace `name` property in child element with `data` property of parent, names doesn't have to be same, eg if child has a property `user` with type `Object`(first letter caps) then your binding will be `user={{data}}`
- If you want you can replace `{{}}` with `[[]]`, unless you want to propagate change from child to parent in which case you will have to add another parameter to `name` property namely `notify` and set its value as true, something like

  ```
  name:{
   type:String,
   notify:true
  }
  ```
- In your case(with ajax call) listing `name` and `data` inside `properties` is optional, but i'll recommend it as it makes it easy to add new features to a property(like notify) and also makes it easy to track all the `properties` in a large element.
- For more details on `properties` and `data-binding` checkout these links. [properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties), [data-binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding)

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">


<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>
    Name from App: {{data.name}}
    <br>
    <my-form name={{data.name}}></my-form>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-app',
    properties: {
      data: {
        type: Object
      }
    }
  });
</script>



<dom-module id="my-form">
  <template>
    Name from Form: {{name}}
    <br>
    <my-name name={{name}}></my-name>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-form',
    properties: {
      name: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  });
</script>

<dom-module id="my-name">
  <template>
    Name from Name: {{name}}
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-name',
    properties: {
      name: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  });
</script>


<my-app data='{"name":"User1"}'></my-app>
```