# Bind iron-ajax response into nested element's property

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have the same problem as this question: "[Polymer How to pass returned iron-ajax string into another polymer element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38338962/2858044)", but the answer didn't solve my problem.

I have two custom elements (below), and I want to bind the response from `<iron-ajax>` into a property (`pagination_options`) of `a-pagination`. In `a-pagination`, if I check the property value using `console.log`, `pagination_options` is always logged as `undefined`. Another property I'm binding (`url`) is always populated. Why is `pagination_options` undefined?

`table-list` element :

```
<dom-module id="table-list">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="table-list.css" />
    <template>
        <iron-ajax url=[[url]] last-response={{response}} params=[[params]] auto></iron-ajax>
         <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response.data}}" as="item">
            <div>[[item.content]]</div>
         </template>
        <a-pagination url=[[url]] pagination_options={{response.pagination}}></a-pagination>
    </template>
    <script>
       Polymer({
          is: "table-list",
          properties: {
            url: String,
            params: Object
          }
       });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

`a-pagination` element :

```
<dom-module id="a-pagination">
    <script>
       Polymer({
        is: "a-pagination",
        properties: {
          url: String,
          pagination_options: Object
        },
        ready: function(){
          console.log(this.url);
          console.log(this.pagination_options);
        }
       });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Usage:

```
<table-list url="http://localhost/api/v1/article" params='{"page": 1}'></table-list>
```

Example AJAX response:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [{
    "id":  "1",
    "content": "content 1"
  },
  {
    "id":  "2",
    "content": "content 2"
  }],
  "pagination": {
    "total_page": 1,
    "per_page": 10,
    "current_page": "1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the `ready` lifecycle event always occurs before the AJAX response event, so when you log the property in `ready()`, you're actually logging the initial value of `pagination_options` (which is `undefined`).

Instead, you should use an [observer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers) like this:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'a-pagination',

  observers: ['_paginationChanged(pagination_options)'],

  _paginationChanged: function(pagination_options) {
    console.log(pagination_options);
  },
  //...
});
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: "table-list",
    properties: {
      url: String,
      params: Object
    },
    ready() {
      // fill response asynchronously to simulate AJAX event
      this.async(() => {
        this.response = {
          "status": "success",
          "data": [{
            "id": "1",
            "content": "content 1"
          }, {
            "id": "2",
            "content": "content 2"
          }],
          "pagination": {
            "total_page": 1,
            "per_page": 10,
            "current_page": "1"
          }
        };
      }, 1000);
    }
  });

  Polymer({
    is: "a-pagination",
    properties: {
      url: String,
      pagination_options: Object
    },
    
    observers: [
      '_paginationChanged(pagination_options)'
    ],
    
    ready() {
      // Don't log `pagination_options` in the `ready`
      // callback, since the AJAX request that fills
      // it might not yet have occurred, and the
      // resulting data bindings might not yet have
      // taken effect. Use observers instead.
      console.log('ready(): url', this.url);
      console.log('ready(): pagination_options', this.pagination_options);
    },
    
    _paginationChanged(pagination_options) {
      console.log('_paginationChanged(): pagination_options', pagination_options);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <div>See console log</div>
  <table-list url="http://httpbin.org/get"></table-list>

  <dom-module id="table-list">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="table-list.css" />
    <template>
      <iron-ajax url=[[url]] last-response={{response}} params=[[params]]></iron-ajax>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response.data}}" as="item">
        <div>[[item.content]]</div>
      </template>

      <a-pagination url=[[url]]
                    pagination_options={{response.pagination}}></a-pagination>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/bgWxPG?editors=1010)

Comment: thanks @tony19, that's working.. I will read that documentation.

Comment: @itx No problem :)

Comment: excusme for troubling you, I have new problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41821138/2858044) can you help me? :)