# Different current target using on-tap on paper-button with iron-icons

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Why current `target` on-tap is different using `paper-button` with `iron-icons` and `paper-button` without `iron-icons`?

```
  <dom-module id="button-tap">
    <template>
    <paper-button on-tap="_getData">without icon</paper-button>
    <paper-button on-tap="_getData"><iron-icon="icons:thumb-up"></iron-icon> with icon</paper-button>
    </template>
  </dom>
```

The current `target` is `paper-button` if not using `iron-icons` (child element).

How can I get `paper-button` as current `target` if using a child element?

[image]

[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWgvdx)

Comment: because you have an element wrapped inside event delegation by default events bubble up side direction

Comment: @VinodLouis how can I get element tapped (`paper-button`) if have child element (`iron-icons`)?

Comment: use current target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the `paper-button` when its contents are clicked, use the [`Event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) (instead of `target`):

> Identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to `event.target` which identifies the element on which the event occurred.

For example:

```
_onTap: function(e) {
  console.log('currentTarget:', e.currentTarget);
}
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    _onTap: function(e) {
      console.log('tap currentTarget:', e.currentTarget);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/communication-icons.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <div>paper-button:</div>
      <paper-button on-tap="_onTap">
        <iron-icon icon="communication:email"></iron-icon>
        Email
      </paper-button>

      <div>
        <div>paper-icon-button:</div>
        <paper-icon-button icon="communication:email" on-tap="_onTap"></paper-icon-button>
      </div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/xgLqdZ?editors=1010)

Comment: thanks again @tony19 
btw can I have your email?, only for learning polymer.. :D

Comment: Sure. My email is in my profile, but you're more likely to get an answer (not necessarily from me) if you post questions on Stack Overflow.